# Cut one stick twice to turn it to be three sticks, what is the probability that the three sticks form a triangle?

Tags: math, probability

Well it is not a program problem. Is there any hint for such quiz?
I am thinking about focusing on two random R1, R2, both of which is in range (0, 1). and supposing R2 > R1
and then fulfill two equation:

```
R1 + (1 - R2) > R2 - R1 // two sticks sum longer then the rest one
|R1 - (1 - R2)| < R2 - R1 // the difference of these two should be shorter the rest one
```

but I cannot move further...

Comment: unless I'm ignoring something, the probability is 1: 3 sticks will *always* form a triangle.

Comment: if your slices are 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, they never form a triangle.

Comment: ah, OK. must be time to go to bed :^\

Comment: In case you're interested, I wrote a blog post about this problem a couple of years ago.  It has a link to the original video lecture where I first heard the problem. [The Broken Stick Experiment](http://www.billthelizard.com/2009/07/broken-stick-experiment.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is 1/4.
Here is the explanation.

Let x is the length of the leftmost stick and y is the length of the rightmost stick.
Then the middle stick has length n-x-y, if the original stick's length was n.

The possible values for x,y are those for which:

1. x > 0
2. y > 0
3. x + y < n

In the plane Oxy this is equivalent to say that the point (x,y) lies within the triangle with vertices (0, 0), (n, 0), (0, n).

Now these three numbers (x, y, n-x-y) form a triangle if all of the three are satisfied:

1. x + y > n - x - y <=> x + y < n/2
2. x + (n - x - y) > y <=> y < n/2
3. y + (n - x - y) > x <=> x < n/2

Again in the Oxy plane these are satisfied when the point (x,y) lies within the triangle with vertices (0, n/2), (n/2, n/2), (n/2, 0).

The area of this triangle is a quarter of the area of the (0, 0), (n, 0), (0, n) triangle, since it's the 'middle' triangle (whose vertices are the midpoints) of the bigger one.

Here is a simple C# program to verify the answer:

```
Random r = new Random();
int count = 0, total = 0, tries = 1000000;
double x, y;

for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++)
{
    x = r.NextDouble();
    y = r.NextDouble();
    if (x + y > 0.5 && x < 0.5 && y < 0.5) ++count;
    if (x + y < 1.0) ++total;
}

Console.WriteLine((double)count / total);
```

Answer (score 3):

Think of (r1, r2) as a point in the unit square.

- Which part of the unit square is allowed for r2 > r1?
- Which part of that leads to three lengths that can form a triangle?

Answer (score 0):

I have just made a program to verify it, and I found it is 1/4:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int nIsTriangle = 0;
        Random ran = new Random(0);

        int nTry = 1000000;

        for (int i = 0; i < nTry; i++)
        {
            double r1 = ran.NextDouble();
            double r2 = ran.NextDouble();
            if (Check(r1, r2)) nIsTriangle++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine((double)nIsTriangle / (double)nTry);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static bool Check(double r1, double r2)
    {
        double first = Math.Min(r1, r2);
        double second = Math.Abs(r1 - r2);
        double third = 1 - Math.Max(r1, r2);
        bool conditionA = (first + second) > third;
        bool conditionB = Math.Abs(first - second) < third;
        return conditionA && conditionB;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some errors in your `Check` method. Remember that `r1` and `r2` are both measured from 0.

Comment: Opps, I just modify the program, yes it is 1/4